# jQuery alternative to keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write something which will detect input in a form field, but I want it to be triggered not just on a keypress but if the user were also to hold a key down for multiple repeat characters, or if they were also to copy & paste something into the input field.

I've tried using `keyup` event but this does not meet all my requirements, and `change` event doesn't seem to be a good fit either.  Please can anyone advise an event which may be more suitable?

Thank you.

Comment: Key held down = `keydown` event. copy + paste = `paste`, `change` or `keyup` (when detecting the keys pressed) event. Note these event have nothing to do with jQuery itself - they're available as part of the DOM. If you can give us some details on your requirements we may be able to offer some more detailed help, or alternative solutions.

Comment: For everything, including `paste` etc. you can use the `input` event, as in `$(element).on('input', function() {...`

Answer (score 6):

You might be looking for jQuery's `input` event.

```
$('inputSelector').on('input', function() {});
```

Look at the following JSFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/MqM76/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML tag `oninput` directly with the name of your function like in this example : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_oninput

Comment: How isn't it a good fit, can you explain what behavior you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that .change doesn't seem to work when I replace .keyup with it.

Comment: I saw a piece of code where they just put the function on basically all the different events : onkeyup, onchange, onmouseup, onkey, etc. to make sure it would be triggered all the time.

Comment: There is also the `oninput` event, maybe this one can help better.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to run the same function for either `keydown`, `keyup` or `paste`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#testingInput" ).on( "keydown keyup paste", function() {
    console.log("running for keydown keyup paste!");
  });

});
```

If not you can just run each one depending on the event:

```
$( "#testingInput" ).on( "keydown", function() {});

$( "#testingInput" ).on( "keyup", function() {});

$( "#testingInput" ).on( "paste", function() {});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhqme6ze/1/